# How to display Zend Studio tasks for one project?

Tags: zend-studio

I'm using Zend Studio 9 and would like to use the tasks feature by adding tags in my code such as @todo etc.  When I open the tasks view, there is a huge list of existing tags from other libraries that cause so much clutter the list becomes too cumbersome to use.  Also, the list displays task tags for all my projects at once, which adds even more clutter.  How can I display task tags for the one project I'm currently working in and hide tags from third party libraries? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This works for me in Zend Studio 10:

1. Click on the triangle pointig down in the upper right corner of the tasks window.
2. Select "Configure Contents" (There can be two. The right one is the opening dialog with "Show all items" as the first control.)
3. You can define here a working set, not including the folders containing the third party solutions.

I hope this helps.